# broken chrome-mobile date input cancel behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, mobile, input

If you open a datepicker(input type='date') in chrome mobile, change the date, then click cancel... you get the new date. Cancel doesn't actually do anything in chrome mobile for input type='date'. How can I fix this? What event even gets fired when you click 'cancel'?

I basically want it so that if the user selects **cancel**, the date will not change. It seems as if that is how the control should function. Currently the mobile chrome control has **cancel**, **clear**, and **set** as options, but **cancel** and **set** seem to perform the exact same.

[basic input fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jumpdart/3cdv6qe2/)

```
<input type='date'></input>
```